# How to fetch data api external to form and grid

Tags: magento2.3

i have 1 modal form and 3 input cells a b c when i enter input a and do enter or tab i capture value of a and call api from outside with parameter value of a then i get data from api and i dump It goes to input b and c and adds grid records right below the input modal form, how can I do that? Thank you for reading

Comment: Hi @NaeemDhattiwala thank you for help me. but I still don't understand what you mean